# PhpStorm won't debug

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm, xdebug

I've installed PhpStorm hoping to debug a WordPress site running on my workstation on top of Local (https://localwp.com), which comes with an "Xdebug + PhpStorm" plugin I have installed.

The "zero configuration" has not worked for me. I set breakpoints and request a page in the browser but the breakpoints never get hit.

What else do I need to make this work?

**Appendix I**

- PHP version 7.3.5
- PhpStorm 2020.1.3

**php.ini**

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /Applications/Local.app/Contents/Resources/extraResources/lightning-services/php-7.3.5+8/bin/darwin/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=Off
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

Comment: check if you have proper php_xdebug.dll file for your php version.

Comment: Local comes with xdebug installed so I presume it's already there.  also DLLs are for Windows.  mine is a .so

Comment: I had a problem with setting up phpstorm +xdebug. I switched to vscode and then everything becomes normal

Comment: Which PHP version you are using?

Comment: I installed PhpStorm because I couldn't make VSCode work.  v7.3.5

Comment: Check this URL. see if this has a solution to your problem  https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1585

Comment: not likely because in that post the breakpoints actually trigger

Comment: configuration of xdebug on PhpStorm is not so easy and also there is a lots of other configuration out there you have to worry about it , so i suggest to try with apache NetBeans its easy to use and you will see the errors if your xdebug configuration is not correct

Comment: *"what else do I need to make this work?"* Well ... start with the most basic and obvious thing: show your config / what you did to configure your Xdebug & PhpStorm. Other than that, check the docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: @LazyOne, PhpStorm advertises "zero configuration" for this to work, so I've done no special configuration of it.  having said that, in Settings/Language & Frameworks/PHP/Servers I declared a "local" as localhost:80 with Xdebug selected and checked "Use path mappings".  that has not helped

Comment: @ekkis Enable and collect Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session. It will tell where it tires to connect to if it tries at all. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html

Comment: @LazyOne might I impose on a real-time chat? I'm on Telegram as ekkis

Comment: @LazyOne I'm trying to follow your suggestion of looking at the log but have run into another snag: if I edit the php.ini file to add the logfile to use, when I restart LocalWP it rewrites it and my changes are lost.  I've had to open a ticket on that: https://localwp.com/community/t/editing-php-ini/20932

Comment: @ekkis You need to see xdebug log in order to see if it tries to connect at all, where (IP:port) and what is the outcome. Only then you can see into what may be causing this. For example: 1) on Mac and Linux you may have php-fpm installed as well. It uses the same TCP 9000 port by default for own communications. In such case changing it to 9001 or alike will help in resolving this (in both php.ini and PhpStorm).

Comment: 2) You may use `netstat` or alike (e.g. `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` on Mac) to see if PhpStorm is the one that listens on Xdebug port (when "phone handle" icon is green). 3) It could also be a firewall issue (depends on your OS security settings) 4)  Could be some other issue (e.g. you have IPv6 higher priority than IPv4 on your Mac ... and PhpStorm by default only listens on IPv4) etc etc. I'm not a Mac user and do not use LocalWP so cannot say what else it might be.

Answer (score 0):

In order for PhpStorm / Local / Xdebug combo to work, you'll need to

- Start Local
- Install the addon for Xdebug from within Local
- Restart Local
- Start a site in Local (ie `test`)
- Go to Utilities and click "Add run configuration to PhpStorm" (ignore the error that'll pop up)
- Start PhpStorm and open  `~/Local Sites/test/app/public/app/public` . THAT'S IMPORTANT to open the public folder (that contains your WP root)
- You'll see a "LOCAL" xdebug dropdown on the top right in PhpStorm
- You're all set!

open `/app/public` from within PhpStorm